# Struts2 Bulk Data display using ModelDriven

Tags: struts2, model-driven

I know the basic Concept of Model Driven process.

How ever i would like to know whether the same ModelDriven Interface process can be used to display bulk data on the action tagged response page ?

To explain this with example

Request page is normal has an argument which is action controlled.

On validate of request page an Intermediate process returns with the Array List Object

Response success page has an  Array List of buckets 100

Each bucket of the Array List holds a JavaBean Object of 10 values.

**Question : By ModelDriven Interface process need to display data by looping thru Array List buckets and casting of the Java Bean on the Response page to extract the original data ??**

with regards
karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to understand your question properly.

```
Request page is normal has an argument which is action controlled.
```

not sure what the above line actually mean

ModelDriven Actions provide a model object to be pushed onto the ValueStack in addition to the Action itself.

It provides more convenient than object back java bean.When you have implemented the model driven interface all that mean that framework will place that object on the top of `valuestack`.
That means say i have an object `person` with properties `name` and `age`,in normal approach i have to use java bean type accessor to access name property like

```
 <s:textfield name="name" value="%{person.name}"/>
```

but when i have model driven interface all i need to do is

```
 <s:textfield name="name" value="%{name}"/>
```

since now person is already on top of value stack so i need not to go traverse inside the person object

Comment: Hi
>>i have an object person with properties name and age,in normal approach i have to use java bean


If the Bean has additional values avaliable from the DB..Can this be alos displayed ...?????

Comment: all you need to have getter and setter for the properties as when tag want to refer them OGNL will look for respective getter method and direct property access is never a good way to go